# How do i use Scanner.class two times with a switch /case in between?

Tags: java, input, switch-statement, break

So i an having a problem, i use the scanners like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test{

   public static void main(String[] args){

      Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
      String b = a.nextLine();

      switch(b){

         case "Hello":
            System.out.println("Hello to you");
            break;
         case "Hi":
            System.out.println("Hi to you");
            break;
         default:
            System.out.println("Good day");

            String c = a.nextLine();

            switch(c){

               case "Bye":
                  System.out.println("Bye to you");
                  break;
               case "Good bye":
                  System.out.println("Good bye...");
                  break;
               default:
                  System.out.println("...");

            }
      }
   }
}
```

So i don't get any errors, however when i try to run it i can only get input from b but not from c because of the break;.How do i solve this problem? I have already tried creating a new Scanner after the switch/case however that also didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You're not closing your first switch statement before starting your second. Place a closing bracket `}` after the default statements in the `switch(b)` block. The way it's written now is that your `switch(c)` statement will only execute as a function of the `default:` branch in your FIRST switch statement. Run your code causing the first switch to default and you'll notice that the second switch statement runs.

In summary: Place a `}` after `System.out.println("Good day");`